# Call Scala Functions from Excel/VBA

Tags: excel, vba, scala, dllimport

I know that with C++ one can create DLL files that contain certain functions, which can then be imported into Excel (e.g. via VBA). Let us take the following C++ function

```cpp
double __stdcall square_it(double &x)
{
    return x*x;
}
```

which we assume is incorporated in **square.dll** so that we can use the following VBA import

```vb
Declare PtrSafe Function square_it Lib "square.dll" (ByRef x As Double) As Double
Private Sub TestSub()
    MsgBox square_it(4.5)
End Sub
```

So my question is: is it possible to code a function in **Scala** and then call it from **VBA** in a similar fashion?

Comment: Here's a [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664072/step-by-step-guide-to-get-scala-to-run-on-net) for running Scala with .Net.  Presumably, this could be adapted for use with VBA.

Comment: Scala can produce jar files, since it produces jvm bytecode. So look for ways to run java jars, and they'll apply. A quick scan turned up this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11343769/microsoft-excel-macro-to-run-java-program

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scala is not going to be any different from Java here, and looking at Java questions such as [Can you use Java libraries in a VB.net program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152967/can-you-use-java-libraries-in-a-vb-net-program) and [Calling Java library (JAR) from VBA/VBScript/Visual Basic Classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297341/calling-java-library-jar-from-vba-vbscript-visual-basic-classic), there are not good solutions to get the same level of integration you have with VBA/C++ in VBA/Java or VBA/Scala.

You can always use any external channel to comunicate between your VBA and your Scala, such at a shell, the file system, or even http, but that's not going to be as straightforward and efficient as your VBA/C++ example.

Here is what it could look like comunicating through a shell:

In example.scala:

```
object Example {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val d = args.head.toDouble
    println(d * d)
  }
}
```

In example.vba:

```
Module Example
  Sub Main()
    Dim command As String 
    command = "scala /path/to/example.scala 123"
    Range("A1").Value = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec(command).StdOut.ReadAll
  End Sub 
End Module
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is still a bit unclear to me. Where exactly (or how) would one reference the example.scala file in the VBA example?

Comment: The argument of the `Exec` is a command to be run in a shell, so it basically depends on how you would normally run your scala from a terminal. `sbt run` will run a .scala file in the current directory with a main method. I updated the answer with an alternative, more explicit way to run `example.scala` :)

Comment: When I type `scala C:\example.scala 123` into the command line (i.e. cmd) I get the correct output 15129.0 as one would expect. But when I run the VBA script with `command = "scala C:\example.scala 123"` I get the error "The system cannot find the file specified, runtime error -2147024894 (80070002)". Any idea? :/

Comment: Mhm, when I write `command = "C:\program files\...\bin\scala.bat C:\example.scala 123"` everything works.

Answer (score 3):

`Scala` runs on the `JVM`, and `VBA` does not, Therefore there is no native way to pass objects between them.

There are two alternatives to communicate between `Scala` and `VBA`:

One option is to start a new process for each procedure call and parse the output, as @OlivierBlanvillain suggested in his answer.

I think that the preferred method, is communicating in web sockets, and particularly `http` using a web server.

## Web Server

Use a scala web server (there are tons of them), for example [scalatra](http://scalatra.org/), and each procedure call should be mapped to a http request to localhost:

### Scala server code (with [scalatra](http://scalatra.org/))

```
class ScalaCall extends ScalatraServlet {

  get("/:func/:params") {
       Calling function {params("func")} with parameters {params("params")}
  }

}
```

### VBA Client code

```
Public Function ScalaCall(ByVal func As String, ByVal params As String) As String
  Dim WinHttpReq As Object
  Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
  WinHttpReq.Open "GET",   "http://127.0.0.1/" & func & "/" & params, False
  WinHttpReq.Send
  If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
      ScalaCall = WinHttpReq.ResponseBody
  End If
End Function
```

Calling `ScalaCall("f","x")` on `VBA` should invoke a request to the `scala` server, that will output `Calling function f with parameters x`

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Obba](http://obba.info/) - A Java Object Handler for Excel, LibreOffice and OpenOffice.